# Redirect to same page using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need after user's action complete the page should exactly remain same using Rails 3.I am explaining my code and code flow below.

> home.html.erb:

```
  <div class="col-md-6" style="float:none; margin:auto;">
        <%= form_for :sdf ,:url => {:action => "scan_report" },:html => {:id =>"form-id" } ,remote: true do |f| %>
        <% if params[:receipt_no] %>
        <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left">Receipt No. Scan :</span>
            <%= f.text_field :Receipt_No,:class => "form-control", :value => params[:receipt_no],:id => "scan-field",:onfocus => ("$('#rcd_btn').submit()") %>
        </div>
        <% else %>
        <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left">Receipt No. Scan :</span>
            <%= f.text_field :Receipt_No,:class => "form-control",placeholder:"Receipt No. scan" %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.submit "Submit",:id => "rcd_btn",:style => "display:none;" %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
<div class="block block-themed" style="display:none" id="whole-div6" >
    <div class="block-title">
        <div class="block-options">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-option enable-tooltip active" data-toggle="block-collapse" title="Toggle block's content"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
        </div>
            <h4>Wood Slip</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="wood-puri">

    </div>
</div>
```

From the above form when user will put the receipt no,lets say `150325006/1` and pressing enter key the below page will display.

> _wood.html.erb:

```
<div class="block-content" style="display:none;">
        <div class="timeline-container">
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Receipt No :</div></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= @sdf.Receipt_No %>"> 
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Date &amp; Time :</div></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= @sdf.Created_On %>"> 
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Deceased Name :</div></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= @hcsy.Deceased_Name %>"> 
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Donor Name :</div></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= @sdf.Doner_Name %>"> 
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Amount :</div></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value= "<%= @woods.Amount %>">
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="block block-themed themed-asphalt">
      <div class="block-title"><h5>Office Use</h5></div>
            <div class="block-content full">
               <%= form_for :vendor,:url => {:action =>"payment" } do |f| %>
                    <div class="totalaligndiv">
                      <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6" style="margin:auto; float:none;"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Select Vendor :</div></span>
                      <%= f.select(:v_name,options_for_select(Vendor.where(s_catagory:  "Woods").pluck(:v_name),selected: "Select vender name"),{},{:class => "form-control",:prompt => 'Selected Vendor'}) %>
                      </div>
                       <div class="totalaligndiv">
                         <%= f.hidden_field :receipt_no, :value => @sdf.Receipt_No %>
                      </div>
                      <div class="totalaligndiv">
                         <%= f.hidden_field :amount,:value => @woods.Amount %>
                      </div>
                      <div class="totalaligndiv">
                         <%= f.hidden_field :date,:value =>@sdf.Created_On %>
                      </div>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                      <div class="tbpaddingdiv1 text-center">
                        <%= f.submit "Add to Payment",:class => "btn btn-success" %>
                      </div>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

From the above page user will select one vendor name when user will click on submit button the db operation will happen and user will stay on the same page which was displaying before(i.e-user will stay on that _woods.html.erb page also after submit) submit button pressed and the "Add to Payment" vanishes till the next receipt no scan.My controller file is given below.

> homes_controller.rb:

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
    def home
        @sdf=TSdf.new
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.js
        end
    end
    def scan_report
           if @sdf=TSdf.find_by_Receipt_No(params[:sdf][:Receipt_No])
                @hcsy=THcsy.find_by_Sdp_Id(@sdf.Sdp_Id)
                @hcsy_deatils=THcsyDetails.find_by_HCSY_ID(@hcsy.id)
                @woods=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(1)
                @burn=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(2)
                @good=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(3)
                @swd=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(5)
                @photo=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(6)
                @vendor=Vendor.new
                flash[:notice]=" number matched"
            else
                splitted = params[:sdf][:Receipt_No].split('/')
                receipt = splitted[0]
                table_id = splitted[1]
                @sdfs=TSdf.find_by_Receipt_No(receipt)
                if @sdfs
                    @hcsys=THcsy.find_by_Sdp_Id(@sdfs.Sdp_Id)
                    @fund_details=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Fund_Type_Code(table_id)
                else
                    flash[:notice]="Scan number not found"
                end
            end
    end
    def payment
        @adds=THcsyFundTypeMaster.find_by_Amount(params[:vendor][:amount])
        @vendor=PaymentVendor.create(:Receipt_No => params[:vendor][:receipt_no],:c_date => Date.today.to_time_in_current_zone,:v_date => params[:vendor][:date],:v_amount => params[:vendor][:amount],:v_catagory => @adds.Fund_Type_Name,:v_name => params[:vendor][:v_name],:v_status => "No" )
        if @vendor
            flash[:notice]="Vendor added the payment"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "home"
        else
            flash[:alert]="vendor could not added the payment"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'home'
        end
    end
end
```

> scan_report.js.erb:

```
<% if @fund_details.Fund_Type_Name=="Woods" %>
            $("#whole-div6").css("display", "block");
            $("#wood-puri").html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'woods' ) %>");
            $("#wood-puri").slideDown(350); 
        <% end %>
```

Here inside payment action now i am redirecting home page .But i need user will stay on that rendered `_wood.html.erb:` page after click on add to payment button.Please help me.

Comment: I'm pretty confused. _woods.html.erb is a partial, but I don't see that it is rendered anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried :back? i.e. in controller

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to :back }
end
```

It will redirect to the page from where request was arrived.